# Can I call a classes method using str2func?

Tags: matlab, matlab-class

I am trying to use `str2func` to call different methods of my class depending on a specific properties value (in this case `obj.type`).

So, I have

```
classdef myClass
    properties
           type %# values are different file extensions (LSM, TIFF, OIF etc...)
    end

    methods(public)
          function process(self)
                 %# here I would like to do something in the lines of
                 funHandle = str2func(['@()self.process_' self.type])
                 funHandle() %# E1
          end
    end
    methods(private)
          %# I have a bunch of methods named process_[type]
          process_LSM(self)
          process_TIF(self)
          % etc...
    end
end
```

However, this does not work.  On line *E1* (above) MATLAB complains that class *self* is undefined and Java might not be running?  Is there away to get this to work or do I have to use a switch structure in method *process* to call the type specific methods *process_[type]*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use functional notation here, not dot notation. The following works:

```
funHandle = str2func(['@process_' self.type])
funHandle(self) %# E1
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use [feval](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/feval.html) instead:

```
feval(['@process_' self.type], self)
```